# UTF-8 Angle brackets up and down?

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, characters

I'm looking for angle brackets which point up and down as UTF-8 characters.

Just for clarification: I need two characters, an angle bracket pointing up and one pointing down.

[image: angel brackets up/down sample]

Answer (score 9):

You could use:

- `&#xfe3f;` / `&#65087;` : ︿ aka *«Vertical Left Angle Bracket»*, [ref](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?dosearch=y&page=0F&subpage=E&utf8=%EF%B8%BF)
- `&#xfe40;` / `&#65088;` : ﹀ aka *«Vertical Right Angle Bracket»* [ref](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?dosearch=y&page=0F&subpage=E&utf8=%EF%B9%80)

*Logical and* and *logical or* are two other search terms that should give some options. E.g.:

∧ ⋀ ⋏ ⩑ ⩞ ⩠ [Logical and](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?dosearch=y&page=02&subpage=2&desctext=logical%20and)

∨ ⋁ ⋎ ⩒ ⩣ ⩢ [Logical or](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?dosearch=y&page=02&subpage=2&desctext=logical%20or)

Also check: https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=angle

Answer (score 5):

You can consult one of many UTF-8 character lists available on the Internet.

Example: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm

Specifically:

- [Unicode Character 'MODIFIER LETTER UP ARROWHEAD' (U+02C4)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02c4/index.htm)
- [Unicode Character 'MODIFIER LETTER DOWN ARROWHEAD' (U+02C5)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02c5/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use left or right angle bracket, or lower than / greater than chars, with css rotation :

```
content:"<";
transform:rotate(90deg)
```

Comment: It will work only if you set position to absolute

Comment: You're right, I suppose there are some adjustments, depending on other css properties.I wasn't entering the details, just a way of  how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found these 2 options at www.w3schools.com:

`&#8896;` for ⋀ or `&#x39B;` for Λ

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/694311)

Comment: @Burgi This answer may be wrong, but it's a legitimate attempt to answer the question. As such, we should not flag it. Down voting may be in order however.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

- U+028C ʌ [latin small letter turned v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turned_v) - small letter v
- U+0245 Ʌ [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turned_v) - CAPITAL V
- U+2227 ∧ logical AND - U+2228 logical OR ∨